# Filter not working in Bootstrap TB Grid View

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii, yii-extensions

I am currently trying to implement bootstrap grid view in Yii. This listing works fine, But filter is not working,

My view:

```
<?php 

$obj=$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbExtendedGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'type' => 'striped bordered',
    'filter'          => $model,
    'columns'=>array(

                array(            // display 'create_time' using an expression
                            'name'=>'host_name',
             'value'=>'$data->host_name',
                ),
                array(
                            'name'=>'host_serviceid',
                            'value'=>'$data->host_serviceid',
                ),
                                array(
                            'name'=>'status',
                            'value'=>'$data->status',
                ),
                array(
                                    'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
                                    'template'=>'{edit_date}{update}{delete}',
                                    'htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>'95px'),
                                    'buttons' => array(
                                           'edit_date' => array( //the name {reply} must be same
                                             'label' => 'Add Date', // text label of the button
                                               'url' => 'Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl("NimsoftHostsDetails/View", array("id"=>$data->host_id))', 
                                                  'imageUrl' => Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/images/icons/pencil.png',  // image URL of the button. If not set or false, a text link is used, The image must be 16X16 pixels

                                               ),
                                           ),)

                ),

)); 

?>
```

thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Check your controller for...

```
$model = new YourModel('search');
$model->unsetAttributes(); // clear any default values

if (isset($_GET['YourModel'])) {
    $model->attributes = $_GET['YourModel'];
}
```

Check YourModel "function search()"

Check YourModel in "rules" for fields "safe on search"